# How to write SQL Stored Procedure to ouput a fixed Length/width File

Tags: sql-server, sql-procedure

I am using SQL server 2017, I want to write SQL stored procedure to generate a fixed length/width file without using SSIS or wizard
TABLE:

| EmpID | EmployeeName | Department | Birthdate | Hiredate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | John Doe | Marketing | 1986-08-31 | 2006-04-01 |
| 002 | Jane Doe | Sales | 1975-01-17 | 2000-06-27 |
| 003 | Mark Vaughn | Production | 1993-05-09 | 2017-03-06 |
| 004 | xxxxx xxxxx | xxxxxxxxx | yyyy-mm-dd | yyyy-mm-dd |
| 004 | xxxxx xxxxx | xxxxxxxxx | yyyy-mm-dd | yyyy-mm-dd |

TO

```
EmpID       EmployeeName        Department     Birthdate     Hiredate
001         John Doe            Marketing      1986-08-31    2006-04-01   
002         Jane Doe            Sales          1975-01-17    2000-06-27
003         Mark Vaughn         Production     1993-05-09    2017-03-06
004         xxxxx  xxxxx        xxxxxxxxx      yyyy-mm-dd    yyyy-mm-dd
004         xxxxx  xxxxx        xxxxxxxxx      yyyy-mm-dd    yyyy-mm-dd
```

Where

1.EmpID (10)

2.EmployeeName (40)

3.Department(20)

4.Birthdate(8)

5.Hiredate(8)

Comment: Are you concerned with it actually outputting to a file, or are you primarily looking for a method to take the table and convert it to a fixed width line?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y Problem™. Why exactly don't you want to use SSIS? Have you considered `bcp`? Any other ETL programmes?

Comment: check this out: 
[help me write this query in sql.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A stored proc can't output to a file. A stored proc can be executed via the [sqlcmd utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017) which can output to a flat file. This method is clunky on it's own, output to fixed width columns with no delimiter makes it a tad more fiddly, but it's do-able. The account that runs the sqlcmd needs to have the correct permissions to write a file to target directory. If you are setting it up in SQL Agent you'd set it up as an "Operating system (CmdExec)" step, and the SQL Agent account will need
permissions to write to the target directory.

Here's a very basic example, a query of a table with three VARCHAR columns with lengths of 20, 35, and 35 written out to a flat file with fixed width column lengths of 20, 10, and 15  respectively. Just for fun some leading white space thrown in. Total Fixed row length of 45 characters in the output file.

Example Table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTableName
        (
            Col1 VARCHAR(20) NULL,
            Col2 VARCHAR(35) NULL,
            Col3 VARCHAR(35) NULL
        ) ON [PRIMARY];
GO
```

Insert some example rows:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTableName VALUES
        ('1Character','1','A'),
        ('2Characters','2','bb'),
        ('3Characters','3','ccc'),
        ('35Characters','XXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','XXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
        ('LeadingWhiteSpace','   Text','   ddd');
GO
```

Quick peek at the table:
[image: Quick peak at the table]

Create the stored procedure:

- By default the sqlcmd utility adds a dashed line below the column names to the output of the SELECT statement executed. We don't want that so we'll execute the sqlcmd using  -k command option to remove the default header.

  - We'll create our own fixed width header row using CHAR string function to set the column lengths to the required length and concatenate the columns together to form the header.
  - The sqlcmd utility will capture any messages sent to the client using [PRINT] so we'll use that to output our header row to the flat file.
- In the SELECT we'll CAST each column using the CHAR string function to size the
  columns to their required length.

```
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProc] 
AS
BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON
        --Create the header row and PRINT it.
        PRINT CAST('Col1' AS CHAR(20)) + CAST('Col2' AS CHAR(10)) + CAST('Col3' AS CHAR(15))
        --CAST Columns to their required sizes.
        SELECT  CAST(Col1 AS CHAR(20)) AS Col1,
                CAST(Col2 AS CHAR(10)) AS Col2,
                CAST(Col3 AS CHAR(15)) AS Col3
        FROM dbo.MyTableName;

END

GO
```

Now call the stored procedure using the sqlcmd utility and have it create a flat file.

```
sqlcmd -S MyServerName -d MyDatabaseName -b -E -s"" -h-1 -Q "EXEC dbo.MyStoredProc" -o \\MyUNCName\MyFolderName\MyFileName.txt
```

Command options explained:

- -S Target SQL Server
- -d Target Database
- -b terminate if there is an error
- -E trusted connection
- -s column separator, empty double quoted string, no separator. (Not documented in  SQL Docs).
- -h Rows per header, value of -1 disables the header and by default dashed line below it.
- -Q Run the supplied command line SQL and exit.
- -o The fully qualified name of the output file.

The output file contents.

```
Col1                Col2      Col3           
1Character          1         A              
2Characters         2         bb             
3Characters         3         ccc            
35Characters        XXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYyyyyy
LeadingWhiteSpace      Text      ddd
```

The output file in Notepad++

[image: The output file when viewed in Notepad++]

Comment: +1 for using CHAR to add in the trailing white space. I was planning on adding something like adding a bunch of white space to each column and only selecting the LEFT (X) characters. But I love that.